# How do I get the users input from a list box in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I need help getting the input from the ListBox(labeled lstAge). I need to know so I can convert it to double because I want to make an If statement for the values being used. I will attach what I have in case that helps.

```
'''
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     For count As Double = 16 To 100
     count = lstAge.Items.Add(count.ToString())
Next
    lstAge.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Dim age As Double

    If txtTicket.Text = "N" Or txtTicket.Text = "n" Then
        If age < 30 Then
            lblResult.Text = txtName.Text & ", your insurance cost will be $45. Keep Up the good driving!"
        Else
            lblResult.Text = txtName.Text & ", your insurance cost will be $30."
        End If
    Else
        lblResult.Text = txtName.Text & ", your insurance cost will be $85."
    End If
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Note that you don't need to convert to string your values, a ListBox uses an object type as the Item source: `lstAge.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(16, 101 - 16).Select(Function(n) n).ToList()`. Cast the ListBox `SelecteItem` to a value type when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     For count As Double = 16 To 100
     count = lstAge.Items.Add(count.ToString())
Next
    lstAge.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim age As Double

    age = CDbl(lstAge.SelectedItem.ToString())

    If txtTicket.Text = "N" Or txtTicket.Text = "n" Then
        If age < 30 Then
            lblResult.Text = txtName.Text & ", your insurance cost will be $45. Keep Up the good driving!"
        Else
            lblResult.Text = txtName.Text & ", your insurance cost will be $30."
        End If
    Else
        lblResult.Text = txtName.Text & ", your insurance cost will be $85."
    End If
End Sub
```

In the `Button1_Click` function, `age` is set by fetching the value of the selected item in the listbox using [ListBox.SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem?view=netcore-3.1), converting that to a string, then converting it to a double using [CDbl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions).

This assumes your listbox does not have multiple columns and you are selecting one item at a time.

Comment: `Dim As Double`? I think you need to edit your answer to `Dim age as Double`

Comment: Thank you, That did exactly what I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you well, you don't know how to get value from ListBox selected item...

To get value from list box, you can use [ListBox.SelectedItem property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_SelectedItem):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim currentage As Integer = DirectCast(lst.SelectedItem, Integer)
    Dim message As String = txtName.Text

    If txtTicket.Text.ToLower() = "n" Then
        Select Case currentage
            Case  16 to 30
                message &= ", your insurance cost will be $45. Keep Up the good driving!"
            Case else
                message &= ", your insurance cost will be $30."
        End Select
    Else
        message = &= ", your insurance cost will be $85."
    End If

    lblResult.Text =  message
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed it to use if statements for this one so I didn't try your method but I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JonathanC, you're very welcome. Why do you need to use `if`'s?

Comment: Its for a class and the instructor covered if statements recently and wants us to prioritize them over others. Thats all.